# MFC List Control Debug Assesrtion Failed

Tags: mfc

I am trying to show a dialog box with a list control filled with values from a CString Array from the parent windows but gettng debg assertion failed error on InsertItem command of ListControl.

Csheetnamesdlg is the child dialog box class.
and m_sheetnames is the listcontrol variable.

```
Csheetnamesdlg tempdlg;

    LVITEM lvItem;

    for(int j=0;j<tempsheetnames.GetSize();j++)
    {
        lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
        lvItem.iItem = 0;
        lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
        tempstring=tempsheetnames.GetAt(j);
        lvItem.pszText = const_cast<LPTSTR>((LPCTSTR)tempstring);
        tempdlg.m_sheetnames.InsertItem(&lvItem);
    }


    tempdlg.DoModal();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use a member list control until the dialog is created. The Dialog and all of its children is created after you called DoModal.

So the correct way is to fill the list box in OnInitDialog or DoDataExchange.

Tipp: Always give aus the line and statement were you get the ASSERT

In this case I am sure that a m_hWnd handle is NULL, so this tells you the reason.

Comment: I am new to MFC Programming. I googled about DDX but all articles describe of getting data from chil to parent dialog not vice versa. Could you suggest any good DDX tutorial for passing data from parent to child dialog or could you show  how to change the above code for DDX.

Comment: There is no real DDX tutirial I know. Also DDX alone is bnot capabale to transfer list Contents to a list box control.